# Semantic UI horizontal cards

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

With this code below, I get vertical cards, one above another:

```
<div class="ui container">
      <div class="ui card">
        <div class="card header">
        Card1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui card">
        <div class="card header">
        Card2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui card">
        <div class="card header">
        Card3
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui card">
        <div class="card header">
        Card4
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui card">
        <div class="card header">
        Card5
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui card">
        <div class="card header">
        Card6
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui card">
        <div class="card header">
        Card7
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui card">
        <div class="card header">
        Card8
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Check [this fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fnL73zL0/7/)

What I need is to put these cards side by side, infinitely. If the total width of cards exceeds the window width, an horiontal bar should appar to allow me to scroll horizontally, but a cards must never go under another.

How can I accomplish that inside Semantic UI ? Using grid would limit my number of cards, so there must be another solution that I'm not aware of.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You should really clean up the structure of this - you aren't closing the `ui card` divs

Comment: Really. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
.ui.container {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.ui.card {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Dan, thanks. I´ve tried this and it works, but it has a collateral effect. Everything that I add inside the card gets nowrapped, or in other worlds, all the child elements gets the property of `nowrap`. I need to put a table inside the card, and I expect the result to autoadjust the table text. Check example at [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0yme2m2s/1/).  Is there a way to apply nowrap just the container, not the card contents ?

Comment: @Mendes You can add another class like `h-scroll` and add it to `container` whose elements which you want to be aligned horizontally and add `nowrap` to that class and `important` if required.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what Im looking for

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking out loud here, but with the current configuration of your HTML, I think it may be defaulting the layout to block format. To counter this, try the following changes, allowing for horizontal scroll as well:

```
.ui.card { display: inline-block; overflow-x: scroll; }
```

Adding the overflow scroll should add a horizontal scrolling mechanism to your cards. Hope this helps!